# Do I need to Unregister Events in this situation to prevent memory leak?

Tags: c#, events

I register and unregister the Events like this. It this necessary to unregister like this?

```
void DoSomething()
{
    using (MyObject ob = new MyObject())
    {
        ob.Start += Ob_Start;
        ob.Completed += Ob_Completed;
    }
}

void Ob_Start(object sender, eventArgs e)
{

}

void Ob_Completed(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    ((MyObject)sender).Start -= Ob_Start;
    ((MyObject)sender).Completed -= Ob_Completed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would prevent memory leaks. Leaving the event subscription prevents garbage collection on the object.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)